# Push and pop in Navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iPhone apps, I have a problem with navigation controller
at push and pop view, for example I have three views i,e A , B and C
respectively, in that I am going(push) to A-->B-->C and also coming
back (pop) C-->B-->A its working.

case 1: Now my requirement is as
follows A->C then i need to move from C->B so how can i do this? in
this case i'm using push(It's working).

case 2: But when i'm going
A->B->C and coming back from C->B i need to use pop NOT Push.   So How
can use Push and pop operations in case1 sand case2.   Now i'm writing
in the following way.

```
    // A-->C and C-->B  or if [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]
```

I used this code:

```
    CategoryClass *class=[[CategoryClass alloc]initWithNibName:@"CategoryClass" bundle:nil];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:class animated:YES];

    // A-->B-->C(push) for back C-->B or if [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] i want to use this code
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

How can I compare whether the `objectAtIndex:0` and `objectAtIndex:1`

Comment: Why is the entire thing in a blockquote?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *views=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[views removeObjectAtIndex:[views count]-2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers=views;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

try this change the value instead of 2 i think this will help you

Delete the stack values and move to the page you want to.......

thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example: (read comments =) )

```
UINavigationController *navController;
UIViewController *viewControllerA, *viewControllerB, *viewControllerC;
[navController pushViewController:viewControllerA animated:YES]; // -> A
// some time passed
NSArray *currentViewControllers = [navController viewControllers]; // <- on stack now
NSMutableArray *newStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:currentViewControllers];
[newStack addObject:viewControllerB]; // <- adding B
[newStack addObject:viewControllerC]; // <- adding C
[navController setViewControllers:newStack animated:YES]; // <- setting new view controllers stack: A, B, C

// returning to B: pop viewControllerC
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
// or
[navController popToViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

We welcome you, its not a problem that you are new, we are here to guide yu with proper solution, 
so dear fellow, first make some changes in appdelegate file which is:

```
storyboardName = [AppHelper isPhone] ? @"Main_iPhone" : @"Main_iPad";
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
navController = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];


     UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
     UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    MainMenu *controller = (MainMenu*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MainMenuiphone"];
    [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
     self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

and after that use this code for pushing views:

```
 ANYVIEWCONTROLLER *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ANYVIEWZID"];
 [ [self navigationController] pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```